# Why is NMAP showing more hosts than expected?

Tags: kali-linux, nmap, scanning

I am using VMware Workstation, and I have a few VMs installed. When I turn on Kali VM (`192.168.140.13`) and Windows 10 VM (`192.168.140.15`) and run NMAP on Kali. I received the following output:

```
└─# nmap 192.168.145.0/24
Nmap scan report for 192.168.140.1
Nmap scan report for 192.168.140.2
Nmap scan report for 192.168.140.15
Nmap scan report for 192.168.140.254
Nmap scan report for 192.168.140.13
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (5 hosts up) scanned in 10.72 seconds
```

The question is why is it showing 5 hosts up? I know the default gateway is `192.168.140.2`. But, what about `192.168.140.1` and `192.168.140.254`?

thank you!

Comment: Why is this about nmap? If ping or arping also turns up these IP addresses, would this become a ping or arping problem? I'm stating it's probably not about Kali Linux or nmap, but about the VMware environment.

Comment: Just noticed that the scan is about 192.168.145.0/24 and the results within 192.168.140.0/24. Now I'm confused.

Comment: The only reason for that to happen is for the NAT server to change. That happens if you do a Workstation upgrade and there was such an upgrade just a few days ago. The upgrade was automatic so you would have just clicked yes. Nothing to be concerned about as you as still scanning your whole network including the internal NAT segment.

Answer (score 0):

Please see here:  [NMAP scanning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377787/how-to-scan-an-entire-network-using-nmap#:%7E:text=for%20entire%20scan%20you%20should,1.1%2D255.1.)

You are scanning your overall subnet so you see everything in the overall subnet.   Entirely normal

VMware Workstation has an internal DHCP server for NAT which facilitates the scanning in 192.168.x.y including the subnet from the internal DHCP server.

I am in Kali here and can do this also.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I completely understand but from where I got this IP address 192.168.140.1 and this 192.168.140.254 in my output?

Comment: That is the same thing overall. NMAP can do both 192.168.NNN.y and 192.168.x.y